# Spring MVC 3.1 App: AbstractApplicationContext#refresh called multiple times during application startup

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, spring-insight

I have a REST web service built with Spring MVC, with annotation-based configuration and plus a web.xml in which `org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` is specified to be used.

During startup of the application in the log file I see some of the lines 3 times. (Hibernate initialization - `SchemaUpdate`, `TableMetadata` etc..., then `configWebApplicationContext`, then `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean`, then `requestMappingHandlerMapping`... and in this sequence 3 times).

The application starts with no errors and I can use the REST endpoints.

My concern is whether because of this my application will use more memory or cause some unpredicted behavior? Any insight is helpful.

Here's a screenshot of the application start-up captured by Spring Insight:

[image]

Comment: okay, I hope it's clearer now ..:)

Comment: how many dispatcher servlets do you have?

Comment: It turns out I have 2. One in `WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer` in onStartup method, and one in web.xml in <servlet> declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I see, excerpt for the longer startup time, it actually doesn't use more memory, so that's good.

As stated in the [JavaDoc API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29), it loads or refreshes the persistent representation of the configuration.

And [@gigadot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507546/gigadot) pointed good in the [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514972/spring-mvc-3-1-app-abstractapplicationcontextrefresh-called-multiple-times-dur#comment16846121_12514972), that I might have multiple dispatcher servlets, and I had two, `WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer` in onStartup method, and one in web.xml in  declaration. I removed the one in the web.xml, and now I had 2 calls to `#refresh` on startup instead of 3, and the memory consumption was the same.